# looping over matfiles - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a series of matfiles named m1...m38. I need to be able to access all of them at once, so I use the commands:

```
fileList=dir('cleanSample*');
m1=matfile(fileList(1).name);.....
```

I hardcoded all of the matfile statements.

I then need to loop over all of these files and extract a specific row from the matrix contained within:

```
for i=1:num1
    arrWrite=m1.outputArray(i,:);
    for j=2:num2
        thename=sprintf('m%i',j);
        addArray=thename.outputArray(i,:);
```

However on the last line, I get the error: "Attempt to reference field of non-structure array."   Is there a way to do this without looping over all of the matfiles?

edit:  its about 20 GB worth of matfiles, so I can't store them all in memory simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your matfile objects into a cell array instead of naming them in sequence:

```
for ii=1:length(fileList)
    m{ii} = matfile(fileList(ii).name);
end

for i=1:num1
    arrWrite = m{1}.outputArray(i,:);
    for j=2:num2
        addArray = m{j}.outputArray(i,:);
```

I don't really understand your indexing, but you get the idea...

Comment: If you look to the edit, he can't load all matfile in memory. So he needs to open them one by one and change what he have too. The main problem isn't the loop. Because I did well. The problem is how to store back.

Comment: matfile objects don't load the contents into memory: they're just handles to the files.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because `thename` isn't a structure. It a string.

```
thename=sprintf('m%i',j);
```

So `outputArray` isn't a variable of this string. It a variable from your matfile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that loops over the files and extracts a particular variable, with that particular variable you do can what you want.  For this I stored these variables in a `cell` because I did not know what you want to do with those variables or of what type the variables will be; a `cell` is like an array but with less restrictions on what its entries can be, it uses `{}` to access an element and `()` to access sub-cells.

```
function TestMFiles
fileNamePrefex = 'm';
numFiles = 38;

%// Pre-Initialize the matrix to save the files in
all2ndEntries = cell(numFiles, 1);

for k = 1:numFiles
  %// temporarily store the wanted variables a in variable
  currFileName = [fileNamePrefex num2str(k)];
  currFile = load(currFileName);
  currMat = currFile.Mat;

  %// Store the wanted entries in a cell
  all2ndEntries{k,1}  = currMat(2,1);
end

%// Do with cell want you want to do
disp(all2ndEntries);
end
```

If memory is a problem, then you might want to put a `pack` command somewhere in the file, this calls the garbage collector and such like.  Although it is rather slow.